# UDP или Websocket

Tags: java, protocol

Хочу организовать программу в которой ~1-3 секунды пользователь отсылает запрос на сервер который должен обработать быстро информацию и отправить ответ. Важен отклик, главное чтобы информация быстро поступила пользователю. Задумываясь о выборе протокола я естественно вывел для себя два претендента `UDP` и `Websocket`, и мне хотелось бы спросить что лучше справиться с большим кол-во пользователем, надежнее, и быстрее по отклику?

Comment: Websocket однозначно

Comment: UDP однозначно быстрее, только код для работы с WebSocket-ами будет занимать в 20 раз меньше места. Кроме этого для вебсокетов легко включить шифрование в виде TLS, с UDP у вас снова будут большие сложности.